# Connecting to MySql server running in a Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a little problem, I can't seem to connect to mysql server community edition running inside a docker container.

I can easily connect to mysql server using the cli by using:

```
docker exec -it mysqlserver mysql -uroot -p
```

But if I try to connect with any other database connector, like DataGrip or MySql Workbench, I get an access denied.

But I changed nothing in the configuration files. I set ip as localhost, using the default 3306 port that the container exposed. username I keep as root and the password is exactly the same but it still keeps failing.

Am I missing something, not understanding anything properly?

Some help would be  greatly appreciated!

Extra info: I am using MacOS, running the container with Docker for Mac and I am using as of this moment the latest MySql database version.

Comment: `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: I am not using a docker-conpose.yml or should i be using one? I am new to docker, trying to understand it.

Comment: I asked because you give absolutely *no* info on how you run it and what your settings are.

Answer (score 1):

your container doesn't contain other connectors, try to publish port when you run your container with `docker run --name mysql -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 ....` to link port. And you can connect you to the container with your local cli. Try this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: I tried it but I keep getting the samen errors, only way i am able to connect to mysql server running in the contrainer is trough docker itself using:
`docker exec -it mysql  mysql -uroot -p`

using an 'external' method keeps leading to an acces denied, I really feel like I missing a key piece of information that I have to know about how the containers work.

Comment: Worked for me, with docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 --name test -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:latest
Check logs and wait for mysql starts completly, you can connect inside container to verify. And after from your host mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p

Answer (score 1):

Below is the `docker-compose.yml` that I used to start up a MariaDB instance for testing some queries. MariaDB is API-compatible with MySQL, so no difference.

```
version: "2"

services:
  db:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb/data:/bitnami
    ports:
      - "9001:3306"
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ChangeMeIfYouWant
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - "9010:80"
    links:
      - db:db
```

The image is downloaded and the container created and started via `docker-compose up`. Afterwards, I can easily connect to it using JetBrains DataGrip.

host: localhost
port: 9001
user: root
password: ChangeMeIfYouWant